# Convergent series, is this telescoping?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\left(x_{n}\right)_{n}\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $v_{n}:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}|x_{k+1}-x_{k}|$. If $\left(v_{n}\right)_{n}$ is bounded, prove that both $\left(v_{n}\right)_{n}$ and $\left(x_{n}\right)_{n}$ are convergent

For the first proof I said:

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}|x_{k+1}-x_{k}|\left(|x_{n+2}-x_{n}|-1\right)\geq0$ (help with that $-1$...)

$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}|x_{k+1}-x_{k}|\geq\sum_{k=1}^{n}|x_{k+1}-x_{k}|$

$v_{n+1}\geq v_{n}$

So $\left(v_{n}\right)_{n}$ is increasing and as it is bounded, it is thus convergent. (I had problems with that -1 not knowing how to justify in that case it is non negative, is this the correct way to proceed?)

For the second proof, I thought of telescoping series but I'm not sure is this helps at all.. Thanks to all who can give me a hand with this :)

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (x_{k+1}-x_k)$ is absolutely convergent, thus convergent. So, compute its partial sums explicitly by telescoping (you should obtain $S_n=x_{n+1}-x_1$).

Comment: What does $\;(x_n)_n\;$ mean? Is it just your way to denote a sequence?

Comment: @DonAntonio yes :) In class they use that notation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

(1) A series with non-negative terms converges iff its partial sums' sequence is bounded (further hint: monotone non-descending sequence bounded above)

(2) If $\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\;$ converges to $\;S\;$ , then

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Na_n=S$$

Comment: @DavidMitra, don't get your point:

$$S=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N (x_n-x_{n-1})=\lim_{N\to\infty}(x_N-x_0)\ldots$$ ...but I wanted the OP to come up with this. BTW, you *also* mentioned absolute convergence => convergence, so I thought it'd be easier.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks! I thought about that too but is it exactly same $x_{k+1}-x_{k}$ and $x_{n}-x_{n-1}$?

Comment: Well, you're right @David. Thanks, that's not the way I wanted it to show. I shall edit it.